# Simpler Jquery Slider code improvement

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have coded a simple Prev-Next Button slider using Jquery, The next button is working properly but when we click Prev button quickly multiplet times than it Doesn't wait for animation to complete and start showing white space...

**Fiddle:-**
https://jsfiddle.net/pnjcr6sw/

**Code:-**

**Css**

```
<style>
    *{ margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box;}
    .slider { width:320px; overflow:hidden; margin:50px 0 0 50px; max-width:100%;}
    .slider ul { float:left;}
    .slider li { float:left; list-style:none;}
    .pager{ float:left; margin:5px;}
    .pager span { width:15px; height:15px;background:#000; border-radius:50%; display:inline-block; margin:0 5px; cursor:pointer; color:#fff;}
    .pager span.active { background-color:#f00;}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li title="First"><img src="story1.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li title="Second"><img src="story2.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li title="Last"><img src="story3.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var slider_w = $('.slider').width();
        var total_li = $('.slider li').length
        var total_w = $('.slider').width()*total_li
        $('.slider ul').width(total_w);
        // counter

        // next button
        $('a.next').click(function(){
            $('.slider ul').animate({marginLeft:'-' + slider_w }, function(){
                $('.slider li:first').appendTo('.slider ul');
                $('.slider ul').css('margin-left','0');
            });
        });

        //prev button
        $('a.prev').click(function(){
            $('.slider li:last').prependTo('.slider ul')
            $('.slider ul').css('margin-left','-=' + slider_w )    
            $('.slider ul').animate({marginLeft:'+=' + slider_w})
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Similar to the two answers: https://jsfiddle.net/pnjcr6sw/6/
The question is whether you want to have the animation blocked if the user clicks quickly multiple times or whether it should skip the images in between...

Comment: @Johannes I want it to work like next button...

Comment: Do you really want that? Because if you click 100 times you have to wait until the animation stops... So in general I would advice you to block this on both buttons. Bug or feature? ;)

Comment: At least I will reach to 100th image in this case, but if I will block it then it will take more time to reach 100th image...so.

Comment: Mh, ok. So a solution could be to set the viewport (so the image you see) to the center, e.g. you have at every time at least one picture to the left and one to the right, so the change of the order isn't visible at any time. Maybe you will get problems using your code for only 2 images...

Here is a quick (and sometimes ugly) workaround for your first problem, but it now reacts different on going for- and backwards, because of this order-problem I mentioned above: https://jsfiddle.net/pnjcr6sw/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if your animation is still running.

```
if( $('.slider ul').is(':animated') ) { ... }
```

And then add `return;` to stop the prev click handler from doing it's thing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var slider_w = $('.slider').width();
var total_li = $('.slider li').length
var total_w = $('.slider').width()*total_li
$('.slider ul').width(total_w);
// counter

// next button
$('a.next').click(function(){
$('.slider ul').animate({marginLeft:'-' + slider_w }, function(){
 $('.slider li:first').appendTo('.slider ul');
 $('.slider ul').css('margin-left','0');
});
});

//prev button
$('a.prev').click(function(){
    if( $('.slider ul').is(':animated') ) {
        return;
    }
$('.slider li:last').prependTo('.slider ul')
$('.slider ul').css('margin-left','-=' + slider_w ) 
$('.slider ul').animate({marginLeft:'+=' + slider_w})
});

});
```

```css
*{ margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing:border-box;}
.slider { width:320px; overflow:hidden; margin:50px 0 0 50px; max-width:100%;}
.slider ul { float:left;}
.slider li { float:left; list-style:none;}
.pager{ float:left; margin:5px;}
.pager span { width:15px; height:15px;background:#000; border-radius:50%; display:inline-block; margin:0 5px; cursor:pointer; color:#fff;}
.pager span.active { background-color:#f00;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
<ul>
<li title="First"><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8jO_wS_uLik/TdDQZh-4PrI/AAAAAAAAA6A/6pHEqZwFQdg/s320/Amazing+Building+Pictures+4.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li title="Second"><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8jO_wS_uLik/TdDQZh-4PrI/AAAAAAAAA6A/6pHEqZwFQdg/s320/Amazing+Building+Pictures+4.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li title="Last"><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8jO_wS_uLik/TdDQZh-4PrI/AAAAAAAAA6A/6pHEqZwFQdg/s320/Amazing+Building+Pictures+4.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="prev">prev</a>
<a href="#" class="next">next</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but can we make it work like the next button

Comment: I mean rather than stopping the button to do any thing, could we make it to  wait for the the animation to end and then do its work

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `if ($(elem).not(':animated')) { // more animation }`. Check out the documentation for more details on this: (http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)